# Select from DB be specifying criteria for nested collection

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have entity structure like this (annotations and identificators are omitted):

```
   public class A {
      List<B> bList;
    }

    public class B {
      List<C> cList;
    }

    public class C {
      String name;
    }
```

How I can write Criteria (or HQL/JPQL query)  to retrieve all instances of `A` where `C.name` equals to "Peter"?

I.e. like this:

`SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.bList.cList.name = 'Peter'`

Comment: As there are lists involved here, you might want to be a bit more explicit with the requirement.

You mean all instances of A that have at least one B with at least one C with C.name equal to "Peter"?

Answer (score 0):

RUN this (JPQL)  and let me know your result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a FROM A a
WHERE
EXISTS
( 
    SELECT b FROM B b
    WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT c FROM C c WHERE c.name = "Peter" AND c.b_id = b.b_id )
    AND b.a_id = a.a_id
)
```

- I assume that a_id is PK of A
- b_id is PK of B, b.a_id reference to A.a_id
- c.b_id reference to B.b_id

Answer (score 0):

HQL Query should be like

```
Query query = session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM A AS a WHERE a.bList.cList.name = :cname");
query.setParameter("cname", "Peter");
return query.list();
```

I assume your entity relationship as follows

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_A")
public class A {
@OneToMany(mappedBy="a")
List<B> bList;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_B")
public class B {

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="a_id")
private A a;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="department")
List<C> cList;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_C")
public class C {

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="b_id")
private B b;

@Column(name="name")
String name;
}
```